# Is there a way to easily find DLC for a game on the Vita?

Tags: psn, ps-vita

When I search for DLC on the PS3/4 I can just go into the PlayStation Store, search for the game and bellow it lists some DLC but there is a button to show all the DLC to the game.

On the Vita however I can't do that, I look for a game (ie. Hyperdimension Neptunia Re;Birth 1) but when I go into it, it gives the description and to buy/download but I don't have the same list as I do on the PS3/4.

When I use the search option I get DLC that's not even for the game I'm looking for. While I do have both Hyperdimension Neptunia games on the Vita some of the DLC I was seeing on the list didn't even belong to either (some looked like they were from Dead or Alive).

So I am wondering, is there an easier way to get all the DLC for only one game to appear?

Comment: You can use your PC (and I assume PlayStation 3 or 4) to browse the store to find Vita DLC. Eg: https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-ca/games/hyperdimension-neptunia-rebirth1/cid=UP0031-PCSE00443_00-NEPTUNEREBIRTH01%3AADD-ONS

Answer (score 2):

The PS Vita doesn't have an option to easily see DLC, but there are two other ways that may work:

- Use Search on the PlayStation Store. If you search the name of the game, you will be able to see other content, including DLC, videos, and themes for that game (where available).
- The LiveArea screen of some games usually include a link to other related content on PlayStation Store. This link can be used to easily find DLC content (e.g. Minecraft: PS Vita Edition has a link like this for Theme/Skin Packs).